# BTS fan fic where Taehyung had the mission of getting Jungkook to join them

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction

Last year I read a BTS fanfic where they had super powers (kinda). But the main part was that near the beginning Taehyung had the mission of getting Jungkook to join them. At the time Jungkook worked at a strip club with Jimin being his best friend.

At another point in the story Jungkook is sold at auction and they rescued him from the ship the auction was on. Jungkook has this power where he could like see your dreams and used it to extract information from a target later in the story. I remember it was on AO3 if that helps.